# Angular2 - Show a loading message, and hide it once the async call finishes

Tags: rest, angular

I am willing to show/hide a **Loading message** once the async call from a REST API finishes, it hides the **Loading message** and show the fetched content instead.

I don't know how to achieve that in Angular2, but in JavaScript, something like this is done:

```
 <h2 id="message">Loading....</h2>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#message').hide();
   //Then Show the newly fetched content
  }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using an ngFor to display the data fetched.

This should work for you:

```
<div *ngIf="!content">Loading...</div>
<div #ngFor="#content of content"></div>
<div *ngIf="content">Now the fetched content appears here!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngIf="!content">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="content"> TODO display the content here </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work with me, maybe because I am running it inside an ngFor ?

Comment: If you have a question about non-working code, then edit your question, post the relevant code, tell what it's supposed to do and what it does instead. I can't guess why your code doesn't work without knowing anything about it.